# How to reference an Object in Unity with C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference, gameobject

Hy Guys
I'm getting the error **CS0120** in Unity at following Code:

> Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static
>   field, method, or property 'PortalScript.Spawn()'

**Script 1:** here I try to create a new `GameObject` on Screen with a certain distance to Player.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class PortalScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Portal; // referenced at Inspector
    GameObject Player = GameObject.Find("Player");

    public void Spawn()
    {
        bool portalSpawned = false;
        while (!portalSpawned)
        {   
            Vector3 portalPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-7f, 7f), Random.Range(-4f, 4f), 0f);
            if((portalPosition - Player.transform.position).magnitude < 3)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                // Instantiate at position.
                Instantiate(Portal, portalPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                portalSpawned = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Script 2:** This script is on the Player. On Case it should call the method Spawn from script 1

```
public class Point : MonoBehaviour
{    

public PortalScript Spawn; 

    void Update()
        {
            score = updateScore;

            switch (score) 
            {
                case 1:
                    PortalScript.Spawn(); // ERROR at this line
                    break;
            }
}
```

If I write the code from script 1 directly into script 2, it works.

My brain stops at that point. Thanks for all your help and let me know if you need more information.

Comment: `Spawn` is not a `static` method.  So you need an _instance_ of `PortalScript` in order to call that method.  It looks like your code should be, oddly enough, `Spawn.Spawn()`

Comment: Thanks :)  that was the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
PortalScript.Spawn(); // ERROR at this line
```

with this:

```
Spawn.Spawn();
```

Comment: Still, that does not answer the question. He will encounter a NullReferenceException, except if I'm not seeing something else. Where is Spawn instantiated?

Comment: @SotirisKoukios-Panopoulos You can't (or shouldn't) instantiate classes that inherit from `MonoBehaviour` yourself. It is best to not think of `MonoBehaviour`  as C# objects in the traditional sense. They should be considered their own unique thing. They are technically the 'Component' part of the Entity Component System architecture which Unity is based upon.

Comment: My bad then, I was thinking in C# only and was not fully aware of the way Unity wires up things

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 could still happen though if OP didn't reference `Spawn` via the Inspector ;)